# Looking for an API integration between Tridion and (CDNetworks and Akamai)

Tags: web8, storage-extensions, deployer-extension

I'm looking for an API integration between Tridion and (CDNetworks and Akamai).
So that, when we place a website, on the infrastructure of a CDN, a purge call is made to that specific CDN provider, when content is updated and/or removed.

I found some older posts and some blog's about Akamai but none about CDNetworks
there is an API for both:
https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/docs/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdnetworks#please-see-the-cdnetworks-api-documentation-for-a-full-list-of-options-and-parameters-for-each-api-call

But I wonder if we should even go into that direction so other suggestions are welcome

Comment: I think you need to **edit** your question and make it a bit more clear what you are looking for, because at current I don't get it.

Comment: Not sure how this differs from https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1397/46. See posts from [Will](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/content-delivery-network-integration), [Mihai](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/extending-content-delivery-storage-in-sdl-tridion-2011-part-1), [Nick](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/storage-extension-for-pages-to-filesystem), [Jaime](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/sdl-tridion-custom-deployer-extension.html).